# Grab content from another website

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

I want to grab anything thats inside the code below on a website.

```
<table class="eventResults byEvent vevent"></table>
```

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Explain the purpose of "grabbing" as it will help us answer the question

Comment: Grabbing = fetching = reading to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function or the [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension for that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying but can't get it to work.

Comment: @Victor, that's unfortunate..?

Comment: @Victor: You should post your code what you are trying also.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to [grab HTML from a site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remote+page+DOM+php), you will want to use a [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) [Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). [PHP has several XML processing packages](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387) to help you with this, be it [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php). An often suggested alternative at SO is [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Since one of the class in the table is `vevent`, the content inside the table could be an [hCalender microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar) (can't tell for sure without seeing the content). If so, you can also use a [microformat](http://microformats.org/) parser, preferably [Transformr](http://github.com/WebOrganics/TransFormr) to save you the work of manually parsing the event data.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the content of the whole page from that website as a string, then use regular expression to extract the substring inside table tags.

Comment: whole page of your target website can be fetched using cURL.